# window.setTimeout not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, timer, window, settimeout

I am trying to ultimately get this code to work:

```
function Timer(callback, delay) {
    var timerId, start, remaining = delay;

    this.pause = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        remaining -= new Date() - start;
    };

    this.resume = function() {
        start = new Date();
        timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    };

    this.resume();
}

var timer;

function onEvent(){
     timer = new Timer(anotherEvent(), 5000);
}
```

But that would not work, so I simplified it to see what might be the problem, and got it down to:

```
var timer;

function event(){
     timer = window.setTimeout(anotherEvent(), 5000);
}
```

and all it does is anotherEvent() immediately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass `anotherEvent` as the argument to the function. What you have now is `anotherEvent()` which **calls** the function and passes its *return value* as the argument.